# Dynamic HTML compile in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a base component in which I want to load dynamic control(component) in that.

Below is my control that i want to load in my another component dynamically.

```
"<mo-text-control-component></mo-text-control-component>"
```

Comment: Use `ComponentFactoryResolver` together with `entryComponents` There are a lot of answers here that describe it

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 for an example.

Comment: thanx @yurzui , gunter